# Controlling VS code with a launchpad

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I really enjoy using vs code but there are some many shortcuts to remember and every new plugins come with a new set.
Of course, I can use the command palette in order to quickly execute a command, but I would like something even more faster such as assigning a shortcut to any of the keys for a device like a Novation Launchpad midi controller.
Stackoverflow is maybe not the best plase to ask this question but I didn't knew where to post it, so is there anyone who tried something like this? I have seen this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOyNUGS4RC8) linking such a device with visual studio so perhaps someone created a software dedicated for vs code already.

Regards,
Johnny -

Comment: any success with this mate?

Answer (score 0):

I've setup this with [MIDI Loupe](https://apps.apple.com/app/midi-loupe/id507075182?mt=12) and [midiStroke](http://charlie-roberts.com/midiStroke/).

`MIDI Loupe` listens your device and logs channel/key/value you just hit on your midi controller - with this tool you inspect your device's output.

Then in `midiStroke` you map controls to shortcuts.

Note: I've found my `midiStroke` setup for `M-Audio Axiom 49` keys don't require values (only key number) but controls (e.g. `record start`) do require it. Also for me letter keys didn't not work if uppercased (e.g. for garageband recording start I need simply `R` button hit and `R` should be `r` in this case)

[Detailed tutorial here](https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/how-to-turn-a-spare-midi-device-into-a-sketch-shortcut-machine-5af9d8a0ad28)